# .htaccess 301 redirect Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am really having trouble with this Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?a=profile&u=(.*)$ /profile/$1 [R=301]
```

I want to make 301 redirect like
`mysite.com/profile/USERNAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querystring is not part of match in RewriteRule, you need to match against `%{THE_REQUEST}` var in `RewriteCond` and then use `%n` to get that match :

This should be your complete htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?a=profile&u=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: [Here it is](http://soundogram.com/index.php?a=profile&u=prazeev) the url i am working, still no change.

Comment: @Prazeev do you have any other rules ?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L]
`

Comment: basically i want  to rewrite mysite.com/inde.php?a=profile&u=USERNAME to mysite.com/profile/USERNAME

Comment: And redirect all the url with a=profile&u=USERNAME to /profile/USERNAME

Comment: @Prazeev i have updated the code. You dont need your other rules just use this.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=profile&u=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php /profile/%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: [Website](http://soundogram.com/index.php?a=profile&u=prazeev) here it is i am trying to do... still needs change... does not eorks

Comment: `RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L]` Here is the rewrite rule next to it

Comment: If that is the next rule you're making an infinite loop of redirects. I think it might be better for you to explain more accurately what you want to achieve and get a complete solution answer instead of blindly trying and mess around.

Comment: am sorry for it. I want to make 301 redirect url  to mentioned above when entered with two parameters as above.